# Django Datepicker form nicely above table view - bootstrap css issue

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a Django app, which Im trying to have a datepicker search form on top of the table nicely.

I am trying to accomplish an arrangement something like this:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/d6h1q]

But I am getting like this:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/TOlqB]

The template html:

```
    ....
    <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <form action="{% url 'employee-attendance_search_date' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {% csrf_token %}

              {{ attendance_search_date_form }}                                  
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>                  

            </form>     
          </div>              

      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
          <thead>
     ....
```

forms.py

```
class AttendanceDateSearch(forms.Form):
    search_date = forms.DateField(label='Date', required=False, widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY-MM-DD"}))
```

I'm using Datepicker for the search field. https://github.com/nkunihiko/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker

Can someone help fix that html/bootstrap code to make that sort of arrangements?

Answer (score 1):

By default your input and your label are setup to work as `display: block`, so they are always `width: 100%`.
If you just want them to arrange side by side(label->input->button). You have to set them to `display: inline-block`. Therefor the elements are only going to use the space that is needed to display them.

Afterwards you can just set margin to the elements to make spaces. Also you should consider, to set a width to the input element in pixels, otherwise it will be very small.

Comment: Tq, would u be able to show the code to do this ? i just inserted the forms.py widget that does datepicker.

Comment: Yes of course, but i can only provide you example code, how it can be.
.attendance_search_date_form is the class for the rendered item, which can be different in your css:

.attendance_search_date_form input {
display: inline-block;
width: 120px;
}

.attendance_search_date_form label {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.attendance_search_date_form button {
display: inline-block; //should be default
}

Comment: Ok will try that out